# What is the problem with these lines of code?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

i am trying to add some content in the shop page of woocommerce. Just tried these codes...

```
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description' , 'sample' );

function sample()
{
    echo "Hello World";
}

?>
```

But Not able to see the desired result.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong??

Comment: what do you mean by not able to see the desired result? what are you seeing instead?

Comment: I am not seeing anything to be precise. @NabeelKhan

Comment: Where did you put your code? This would go in a theme's `functions.php` file or a plugin since it's action-based.

Comment: I put this in the function.php file of the child theme.

Comment: did you enable the child theme?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to add an output buffer. I find a lot of times if I'm echoing something in WordPress and it doesn't show up, adding the output buffering does the trick.

```
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description' , 'sample' );

function sample(){
    ob_start();
    echo "Hello World";
    return ob_get_clean();
}

?>
```